# Split a string into columns and fetch the columns from a json object

Tags: sql, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a string separated by commas, which are the column names in  `my_table`.
`“First_Name, Last_Name, Age”`. I need to split the string with commas and fetch the `columns(First_Name, Last_Name, Age)` from `my_table` from a JSON column called `custom_fields`.

Here is the JSON column below:

```
custom_fields
{
"First_Name": "Vaibhav",
"Last_Name": "Terli",
"Age": "24"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
First_Name | Last_Name | Age
---------------------------
Vaibhav   | Terli     | 24
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: Can you change the string to an array?  Then loop the array to get each field name.  Or, split the string into an array using PHP or some other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier if your JSON in a VARIANT type, then you can use standard Snowflake syntax to call values from individual JSON keys. If your JSON is a string, you can use `PARSE_JSON` function to convert it to VARIANT, see below example:

```
-- Initialize some test data set.
CREATE TABLE json_data_table (
    user_data VARIANT
);

-- Insert your data converting to VARIANT using PARSE_JSON function
INSERT INTO json_data_table (user_data)
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{
    "First_Name": "Vaibhav",
    "Last_Name": "Terli",
    "Age": "24"
}') AS user_data;
```

Now you can select individual keys as follows:

```
SELECT 
    user_data:First_Name AS First_Name,
    user_data:Last_Name AS Last_Name,
    user_data:Age AS Age
FROM json_data_table;
```

The expected output:
[image]